# How to get my regular html and javascript to work in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have written code in javascript and html. The goal of that was to get a user to log in into youtube and once they do, they will see some feed. Now i want to use this code into a reactjs project. the question is how can i do this. I am having trouble doing that. the code below is the html and java script code i wrote. Now the code at the bottom is what i tried to do in reactjs.

```
// Options
const CLIENT_ID = '530254027383-djo7723li5ju3c6t4e2taacvj5idbp50.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const DISCOVERY_DOCS = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest'
];
const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly';

const authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
const signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');
const content = document.getElementById('content');
const channelForm = document.getElementById('channel-form');
const channelInput = document.getElementById('channel-input');
const videoContainer = document.getElementById('video-container');

const defaultChannel = 'techguyweb';

// Form submit and change channel
channelForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const channel = channelInput.value;

  getChannel(channel);
});

// Load auth2 library
function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
}

// Init API client library and set up sign in listeners
function initClient() {
  gapi.client
    .init({
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES
    })
    .then(() => {
      // Listen for sign in state changes
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
      // Handle initial sign in state
      updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
      authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
      signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
    });
}

// Update UI sign in state changes
function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
  if (isSignedIn) {
    authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
    signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
    content.style.display = 'block';
    videoContainer.style.display = 'block';
    getChannel(defaultChannel);
  } else {
    authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
    signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
    content.style.display = 'none';
    videoContainer.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

// Handle login
function handleAuthClick() {
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
}

// Handle logout
function handleSignoutClick() {
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
}

// Display channel data
function showChannelData(data) {
  const channelData = document.getElementById('channel-data');
  channelData.innerHTML = data;
}

// Get channel from API
function getChannel(channel) {
  gapi.client.youtube.channels
    .list({
      part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
      forUsername: channel
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      const channel = response.result.items[0];

      const output = `
        <ul class="collection">
          <li class="collection-item">Title: ${channel.snippet.title}</li>
          <li class="collection-item">ID: ${channel.id}</li>
          <li class="collection-item">Subscribers: ${numberWithCommas(
            channel.statistics.subscriberCount
          )}</li>
          <li class="collection-item">Views: ${numberWithCommas(
            channel.statistics.viewCount
          )}</li>
          <li class="collection-item">Videos: ${numberWithCommas(
            channel.statistics.videoCount
          )}</li>
        </ul>
        <p>${channel.snippet.description}</p>
        <hr>
        <a class="btn grey darken-2" target="_blank" href="https://youtube.com/${
          channel.snippet.customUrl
        }">Visit Channel</a>
      `;
      showChannelData(output);

      const playlistId = channel.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
      requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId);
    })
    .catch(err => alert('No Channel By That Name'));
}

// Add commas to number
function numberWithCommas(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
}

function requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId) {
  const requestOptions = {
    playlistId: playlistId,
    part: 'snippet',
    maxResults: 10
  };

  const request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list(requestOptions);

  request.execute(response => {
    console.log(response);
    const playListItems = response.result.items;
    if (playListItems) {
      let output = '<br><h4 class="center-align">Latest Videos</h4>';

      // Loop through videos and append output
      playListItems.forEach(item => {
        const videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;

        output += `
          <div class="col s3">
          <iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        `;
      });

      // Output videos
      videoContainer.innerHTML = output;
    } else {
      videoContainer.innerHTML = 'No Uploaded Videos';
    }
  });
}
```

now the code above was the javascript and now the code below is the html I used.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

  <style>
    #content,
    #authorize-button,
    #signout-button {
      display: none
    }
  </style>

  <title>YouTube Channel Data</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="black">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">YouTube Channel Data</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <br>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Log In With Google</p>
      <button class="btn red" id="authorize-button">Log In</button>
      <button class="btn red" id="signout-button">Log Out</button>
      <br>
      <div id="content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s6">
            <form id="channel-form">
              <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Channel Name" id="channel-input">
                <input type="submit" value="Get Channel Data" class="btn grey">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div id="channel-data" class="col s6"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="video-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()" onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

the code below is the code i tried to do in reactjs ,but it is not working . Any idea on how i can get it to work or if it is even possible?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import YouTube from 'react-youtube';

/* global gapi */
const CLIENT_ID = '530254027383-djo7723li5ju3c6t4e2taacvj5idbp50.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const DISCOVERY_DOCS = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest'
];
const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly';

const authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
const signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');
const content = document.getElementById('content');
const channelForm = document.getElementById('channel-form');
const channelInput = document.getElementById('channel-input');
const videoContainer = document.getElementById('video-container');

const defaultChannel = 'techguyweb';



export default class youtube extends Component {
// Form submit and change channel
channelForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const channel = channelInput.value;

  getChannel(channel);
});

// Load auth2 library
function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
}

// Init API client library and set up sign in listeners
function initClient() {
  gapi.client
    .init({
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES
    })
    .then(() => {
      // Listen for sign in state changes
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
      // Handle initial sign in state
      updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
      authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
      signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
    });
}

// Update UI sign in state changes
function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
  if (isSignedIn) {
    authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
    signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
    content.style.display = 'block';
    videoContainer.style.display = 'block';
    getChannel(defaultChannel);
  } else {
    authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
    signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
    content.style.display = 'none';
    videoContainer.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

// Handle login
function handleAuthClick() {
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
}

// Handle logout
function handleSignoutClick() {
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
}

// Display channel data
function showChannelData(data) {
  const channelData = document.getElementById('channel-data');
  channelData.innerHTML = data;
}

// Get channel from API
function getChannel(channel) {
  gapi.client.youtube.channels
    .list({
      part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
      forUsername: channel
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      const channel = response.result.items[0];

      const output = `
        <ul class="collection">
          <li class="collection-item">Title: ${channel.snippet.title}</li>
          <li class="collection-item">ID: ${channel.id}</li>
          <li class="collection-item">Subscribers: ${numberWithCommas(
            channel.statistics.subscriberCount
          )}</li>
          <li class="collection-item">Views: ${numberWithCommas(
            channel.statistics.viewCount
          )}</li>
          <li class="collection-item">Videos: ${numberWithCommas(
            channel.statistics.videoCount
          )}</li>
        </ul>
        <p>${channel.snippet.description}</p>
        <hr>
        <a class="btn grey darken-2" target="_blank" href="https://youtube.com/${
          channel.snippet.customUrl
        }">Visit Channel</a>
      `;
      showChannelData(output);

      const playlistId = channel.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
      requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId);
    })
    .catch(err => alert('No Channel By That Name'));
}

// Add commas to number
function numberWithCommas(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
}

function requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId) {
  const requestOptions = {
    playlistId: playlistId,
    part: 'snippet',
    maxResults: 10
  };

  const request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list(requestOptions);

  request.execute(response => {
    console.log(response);
    const playListItems = response.result.items;
    if (playListItems) {
      let output = '<br><h4 class="center-align">Latest Videos</h4>';

      // Loop through videos and append output
      playListItems.forEach(item => {
        const videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;

        output += `
          <div class="col s3">
          <iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        `;
      });

      // Output videos
      videoContainer.innerHTML = output;
    } else {
      videoContainer.innerHTML = 'No Uploaded Videos';
    }
  });
```